# I get hundreds of errors following basic Xcode tutorial on single view app

Tags: ios, xcode

I decided I should try to learn how to make an iOS app. I've an old MacBook Pro, and I've installed Xcode 7.3, which I think is the most recent version I can use on a CPU this old.

I decided I would follow this basic tutorial:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/BuildABasicUI.html

In other words, I create a project and create a single view app, then I try to view it. I have not written any code. I'm simply trying to run the code that Xcode has auto-generated.

But the code created by Xcode does not run. When the simulator comes up, it is black for a while, then white. When I open the console, I see hundreds of errors. Here are a few of the more interesting ones:

```
 SpringBoard[28470]: |GAXGeneral|info| whitelistedApps and appSelfLockIDs both nil.  No need to enable GAX (Single App Mode)

 SpringBoard[28470]: Installed apps did change.

    Added: {(

        "com.apple.PassbookUIService",
        "com.apple.SharedWebCredentialViewService",
        "com.apple.FacebookAccountMigrationDialog",
        "com.apple.mobilesafari",
        "com.apple.AdSheetPhone",
        "com.apple.share",
        "com.apple.SafariViewService",
        "com.apple.appleaccount.AACredentialRecoveryDialog",
        "com.chernetwork.cher.cher-ios-native",
        "com.apple.CloudKit.ShareBear",
        "com.apple.Preferences",
        "com.apple.WebContentFilter.remoteUI.WebContentAnalysisUI",
        "com.apple.iCloudDriveApp",
        "com.apple.mobileslideshow",
        "com.apple.mobilesms.compose",
        "com.apple.CoreAuthUI",
        "com.apple.MailCompositionService",
        "com.apple.Passbook",
        "com.apple.WatchKitSettings",
        "com.apple.iad.iAdOptOut",
        "com.apple.MusicUIService",
        "com.apple.TencentWeiboAccountMigrationDialog",
        "com.apple.WebViewService",
        "com.apple.TrustMe",
        "com.apple.AccountAuthenticationDialog",
        "com.apple.social.SLYahooAuth",
        "com.apple.Maps",
        "com.apple.PhotosViewService",
        "com.launchdeck.peeroapp",
        "com.apple.managedconfiguration.MDMRemoteAlertService",
        "com.apple.quicklook.quicklookd",
        "com.apple.LoginUI",
        "com.apple.Health",
        "com.apple.MobileAddressBook",
        "com.apple.datadetectors.DDActionsService",
        "com.apple.social.SLGoogleAuth",
        "com.apple.DataActivation",
        "com.apple.Home.HomeUIService",
        "com.apple.ServerDocuments",
        "com.apple.HealthPrivacyService",
        "com.apple.WebSheet",
        "com.apple.camera",
        "com.apple.mobilecal",
        "com.apple.news",
        "com.apple.ios.StoreKitUIService",
        "com.apple.gamecenter.GameCenterUIService",
        "com.apple.reminders",
        "com.apple.PrintKit.Print-Center",
        "com.apple.webapp",
        "com.apple.webapp1",
        "com.apple.gamecenter"
    )}



itunesstored[29232]: (Error) MC: MobileContainerManager gave us a path we weren't expecting; file a radar against them

    Expected: /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles

    Actual: /Users/cherry/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7E725FBD-23F1-4759-BC45-FFC84DC93861/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles

    Overriding MCM with the one true path



 SpringBoard[28470]: *** error reading settings archive file: <SBRootSettings: /Users/cherry/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7E725FBD-23F1-4759-BC45-FFC84DC93861/data/Documents/com.apple.springboard.settings/RootSettings.plist> 

 SpringBoard[28470]: *** error reading settings archive file: <SBRootSettings: /Users/cherry/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7E725FBD-23F1-4759-BC45-FFC84DC93861/data/Documents/com.apple.springboard.settings/RootSettings.previous.plist> 

 assertiond[28474]: assertion failed: 15G19009 13E230: assertiond + 15801 [3C808658-78EC-3950-A264-79A64E0E463B]: 0x1

Mar 22 17:29:01 --- last message repeated 3 times ---

 fileproviderd[28458]: plugin com.apple.ServerDocuments.ServerFileProvider invalidated

 ServerFileProvider[29231]: host connection <NSXPCConnection: 0x7f939ad01260> connection from pid 28458 invalidated

 SpringBoard[28470]: Cannot get managed lost mode file on watch or simulator: -[FMDFMIPManager(Private) getManagedLostModeFileURL]

 SpringBoard[28470]: Normal message received by listener connection. Ignoring.

Mar 22 17:29:06 --- last message repeated 2 times ---

 SpringBoard[28470]: could not find icon for representation -> com.apple.MobileSMS

 SpringBoard[28470]: throwing out icon because it isn't visible in the model : node=<SBApplicationIcon: 0x7ffee38a2de0; nodeID: "com.apple.camera"> com.apple.camera

 SpringBoard[28470]: could not find icon for representation -> com.apple.weather
 SpringBoard[28470]: could not find icon for representation -> com.apple.mobiletimer
 SpringBoard[28470]: could not find icon for representation -> com.apple.videos
 SpringBoard[28470]: could not find icon for representation -> com.apple.mobilenotes
 SpringBoard[28470]: could not find icon for representation -> com.apple.stocks
 SpringBoard[28470]: could not find icon for representation -> com.apple.MobileStore
 SpringBoard[28470]: could not find icon for representation -> com.apple.AppStore
 SpringBoard[28470]: could not find icon for representation -> com.apple.iBooks
 SpringBoard[28470]: could not find icon for representation -> com.apple.facetime
 SpringBoard[28470]: could not find icon for representation -> com.apple.calculator
 SpringBoard[28470]: could not find icon for representation -> com.apple.podcasts
 SpringBoard[28470]: could not find icon for representation -> com.apple.Bridge
 SpringBoard[28470]: could not find icon for representation -> com.apple.compass
 SpringBoard[28470]: could not find icon for representation -> com.apple.tips
 SpringBoard[28470]: could not find icon for representation -> com.apple.VoiceMemos
 SpringBoard[28470]: could not find icon for representation -> com.apple.mobileme.fmf1
 SpringBoard[28470]: could not find icon for representation -> com.apple.mobileme.fmip1
 SpringBoard[28470]: could not find icon for representation -> com.apple.mobilephone
 SpringBoard[28470]: could not find icon for representation -> com.apple.mobilemail
 SpringBoard[28470]: could not find icon for representation -> com.apple.Music

SpringBoard[28470]:  [SBFImageColorSpaceUtilities] failed to create copy with colorSpace=<CGColorSpace 0x7ffee1703480> (kCGColorSpaceICCBased; kCGColorSpaceModelMonochrome; Generic Gray Gamma 2.2 Profile) of original CGImage=<CGImage 0x7ffee3936430> with colorSpace=<CGColorSpace 0x7ffee1664fc0> (kCGColorSpaceICCBased; kCGColorSpaceModelRGB; sRGB IEC61966-2.1)



 com.apple.accessibility.AccessibilityUIServer[29237]: (repeated 51 times(s)): |AXIPC|warning| Could not find server for service: com.apple.accessibility.AXSpringBoardServer

 com.apple.accessibility.AccessibilityUIServer[29237]: (repeated 51 times(s)): |AXSBServer|error| AX SpringBoardServer: Error: Domain:AXIPC Code:0 Reason:The operation couldn’t be completed. Could not find server for service: com.apple.accessibility.AXSpringBoardServer

 com.apple.accessibility.AccessibilityUIServer[29237]: (repeated 22 times(s)): |AXIPC|warning| Could not verify connection. server port was nil


itunesstored[29232]: libMobileGestalt MGBasebandSupport.c:189: No CT mobile equipment info dictionary while fetching kCTMobileEquipmentInfoIMEI

 CoreSimulatorBridge[28478]: Requesting launch of com.chernetwork.cher.cher-ios-native with options: {

        arguments =     (

        );

        environment =     {

            "DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH" = "/Users/cherry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cher-ios-native-gvhjhzxuzjttnhckuwczsgfixacb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator";

            "DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES" = "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib";

            "DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH" = "/Users/cherry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cher-ios-native-gvhjhzxuzjttnhckuwczsgfixacb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib/system/introspection";

            NSUnbufferedIO = YES;

            "__XCODE_BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR_PATHS" = "/Users/cherry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cher-ios-native-gvhjhzxuzjttnhckuwczsgfixacb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator";

            "__XPC_DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH" = "/Users/cherry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cher-ios-native-gvhjhzxuzjttnhckuwczsgfixacb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator";

            "__XPC_DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH" = "/Users/cherry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cher-ios-native-gvhjhzxuzjttnhckuwczsgfixacb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator";

        };

        stderr = "/dev/ttys006";

        stdout = "/dev/ttys006";

        "wait_for_debugger" = 1;

    }


SpringBoard[28470]: Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.

        Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 

        Try this: 

            (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 

            (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 

    (

        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffee3987f20 UILabel:0x7ffee39801b0' '.leading == SPUISearchTableHeaderView:0x7ffee397d5c0.leadingMargin>",

        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffee3988be0 H:[UILabel:0x7ffee39801b0' ']-(NSSpace(8))-[UIButton:0x7ffee39833b0'Show More']>",

        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffee3988c30 SPUISearchTableHeaderView:0x7ffee397d5c0.trailingMargin == UIButton:0x7ffee39833b0'Show More'.trailing>",

        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffee3988170 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[SPUISearchTableHeaderView:0x7ffee397d5c0(0)]>"

    )



    Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 

    <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffee3988be0 H:[UILabel:0x7ffee39801b0' ']-(NSSpace(8))-[UIButton:0x7ffee39833b0'Show More']>



    Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.

    The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.

 SpringBoard[28470]: Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.

        Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 

        Try this: 

            (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 

            (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 

    (

        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffee39848a0 SPUISearchTableHeaderView:0x7ffee397d5c0.bottom == UILabel:0x7ffee39801b0' '.lastBaseline + 8>",

        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffee3984db0 UILabel:0x7ffee39801b0' '.firstBaseline == SPUISearchTableHeaderView:0x7ffee397d5c0.top + 36>",

        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffee39882d0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[SPUISearchTableHeaderView:0x7ffee397d5c0(0)]>"

    )



    Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 

    <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffee3984db0 UILabel:0x7ffee39801b0' '.firstBaseline == SPUISearchTableHeaderView:0x7ffee397d5c0.top + 36>



    Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.

    The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.





 SpringBoard[28470]: -[SBAssistantController _loadPlugin] Assistant failed to load!

 backboardd[28471]: Couldn't find the digitizer HID service, this is probably bad


searchd[29258]: tcp_connection_set_tfo 3 TFO is not yet supported on Simulator

 searchd[29258]: tcp_connection_set_tfo 4 TFO is not yet supported on Simulator

 assertiond[28474]: assertion failed: 15G19009 13E230: assertiond + 15801 [3C808658-78EC-3950-A264-79A64E0E463B]: 0x1

 SpringBoard[28470]: LICreateIconForImage passed NULL CGImageRef image

 backboardd[28471]: SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22 cs_flags=200, task->pid_self=-1

 backboardd[28471]: SecTaskCopyDebugDescription: cher-ios-native[29262]

 backboardd[28471]: SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22 cs_flags=200, task->pid_self=-1

 backboardd[28471]: SecTaskCopyDebugDescription: cher-ios-native[29262]

 backboardd[28471]: SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22 cs_flags=200, task->pid_self=-1

 backboardd[28471]: SecTaskCopyDebugDescription: cher-ios-native[29262]

 backboardd[28471]: SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22 cs_flags=200, task->pid_self=-1

 backboardd[28471]: SecTaskCopyDebugDescription: cher-ios-native[29262]

 backboardd[28471]: SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22 cs_flags=200, task->pid_self=-1

 backboardd[28471]: SecTaskCopyDebugDescription: cher-ios-native[29262]

 cher-ios-native[29262]: assertion failed: 15G19009 13E230: libxpc.dylib + 57882 [66C28065-C9DB-3C8E-926F-5A40210A6D1B]: 0x7d

 assertiond[28474]: assertion failed: 15G19009 13E230: assertiond + 15801 [3C808658-78EC-3950-A264-79A64E0E463B]: 0x1

Mar 22 17:29:55 --- last message repeated 1 time ---

 SpringBoard[28470]: [MPUSystemMediaControls] Updating supported commands for now playing application.

 assertiond[28474]: assertion failed: 15G19009 13E230: assertiond + 15801 [3C808658-78EC-3950-A264-79A64E0E463B]: 0x1

Mar 22 17:29:55 --- last message repeated 4 times ---

 backboardd[28471]: CoreAnimation: updates deferred for too long

 searchd[29258]: tcp_connection_tls_session_error_callback_imp 4 __tcp_connection_tls_session_callback_write_block_invoke.434 error 22
```

So, how do I debug this? Again, I have not written any code. I'm simply trying to run the code auto-generated by Xcode. But it does not run.

I've a lot of questions, but among many things, what is this final line about?

```
tcp_connection_tls_session_error_callback_imp
```

Why would this simple app need a TCP connection? And since it does, why is the TCP connection failing?

Comment: If you used the "single view application" template, the only UI in the app is a plain white screen, until you start adding things. A plain white screen is exactly what I'd expect to see in the situation you describe.

Comment: In the screenshot example that they give, in the tutorial, it seems to suggest that I should see a battery symbol in the top right of the screen.

Comment: Also, are you suggesting that the above errors are normal, and I can safely ignore them?

Comment: Just so you get where my perspective is coming from, I've done a lot of Java development, and I would never expect to see so many errors if I was building a Java app. I'd only expect to see errors if something was actually wrong. That's especially true if I'm only following an introductory tutorial.

Comment: I didn't realize the battery indicator was missing. Between that and your errors, nothing is normal about this situation. It's bad enough that I wold consider the Xcode installation to be suspect at best, and reinstall it.

Comment: The "Reset content" command, in the simulator, seems to have worked.

Comment: Interesting. Glad it worked out!

Comment: Can you please help me out with the framework to list all installed app bundleID

Answer (score 0):

Is there any framework to display all the bundleID of the application installed on the iPhone.